# Objective-C -> How to pass pointer by reference

Tags: objective-c

In C++ I can pass a pointer by reference by doing

```
void someFunction(int * & x) {
     ...
}
```

However, when I attempt to use this same syntax in an Objective-C .mm file,
the compiler yells at me with a linker error saying these are unidentified symbols in the 
arm 7 architecture.

I have a Box2D helper function which is defined as follows

```
bool isBodyCollidingWithDestTerrain(b2Body * body, DestuctibleTerrain * dter, CGPoint * colPt) {
    ...
}
```

I want to be able to pass DestructibleTerrain * by reference so I can assign the pointer to a pointer pointing to the DestructibleTerrain involved in the collision.

My knowledge of Objective-C is limited and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't believe that Obj-C has references...

Comment: Seems odd that they wouldn't implement that.. Is there a workaround or should I modify return type of my function to just be the DestTerrain (I would prefer not to do this...)

Comment: The difference between my post and the one you listed is my code is a C++ function in a .mm file.

Comment: Objective-C will do what C does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use plain C code:

```
bool isBodyCollidingWithDestTerrain(b2Body * body, DestuctibleTerrain ** dter, CGPoint * colPt) {
    *dter = // ...
}
```